# Growth of a completely pivoted Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

Let A be a CP matrix.( A completely pivoted matrix is one such that during the Gauss transformation with full pivoting there is no need to exchange rows or columns) We apply to it Gaussian elimination. I want to prove that
$\begin{align}
g(n,A)&=max\{1,\max_{1\leq r\leq n-1}\Big | \frac{A\begin{pmatrix}
     1 &2 & \cdots &r &r+1  \end{pmatrix}}
     {a_{11}A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & \cdots & r  \end{pmatrix}} \Big |\}
\end{align}$

We consider the matrix:

\begin{align}
A^{(1)}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} &a_{12} &\cdots &a_{1n}\\
0 & a^{(1)}_{22} &\cdots &a^{(1)}_{2n} &\\
. & . &\cdots &.\\
. & . &\cdots &. \\
. & . &\cdots &. \\
0 &a_{n2}^{(1)} &\cdots &a_{nn}^{(1)}  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align} to be the matrix after the first tranformation. Acordingly we define $A^{(r)}$

My work so far:
In general
$\begin{align}
g(n,A)&=\frac{\max_{1<r<n-1}|a^{(r)}_{ij}|}{\max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|}
\end{align}$ Since A CP $a_{11}=max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$.
Hence:
$\begin{align}
g(n,A)&=\frac{1}{a_{11}}\max_{i,j,k}\Big|\frac{A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &2 & \cdots &r &i \\
     1 &2 & \cdots &r &j
\end{pmatrix}}{A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &2 & \cdots &r 
\end{pmatrix}}\Big| \\
&=\max_{1\leq r\leq n-1}\frac{1}{a_{11}\Big | A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &2 & \cdots &r 
\end{pmatrix}\Big|}\max_{i,j,r}\Big |A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &2 & \cdots &r &i \\
     1 &2 & \cdots &r &j
\end{pmatrix}\Big |
\end{align}$.

So it seems that I need to prove that $\max_{i,j,r}\Big |A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &2 & \cdots &r &i \\
     1 &2 & \cdots &r &j
\end{pmatrix}\Big |=\max_{1< r \leq n-1} A\begin{pmatrix} 1 &2 &\cdots &r &r+1 \end{pmatrix}$ but I am stuck. Can someone help?

Comment: Is $g(n,A)=\dfrac{\max_{1<r<n-1}|a^{(k)}_{ij}|}{\max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|}$ a definition? What does $(r)$ mean in $a_{ij}^{(r)}$? What's a completely pivoted matrix? (my guess: pivot rows and columns to maximize every pivot)

Comment: my bad k should be r. I will add more details to the question

Comment: I saw the edit, but I still have some questions.

Comment: I added all the details now @Jean-ClaudeArbaut